# Prefab appears at center of screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate a prefab relative to some transform and it works correctly if I use an in-built prefab.

However, if I create my own prefab and add a rawImage to it, it always renders at the center of the screen.

The code is like this:

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(ArPrefab);
obj.transform.parent = face.transform;
obj.transform.position = face.vertices[8];
obj.transform.rotation = face.transform.rotation;
obj.SetActive(true);
```

Here, if the above prefab is an inbuilt one like sphere, cylinder, that works fine. If I create my own with a rawImage, it doesn't render correctly.

I don't fully understand how the Canvas is set in position, relative to the aforementioned transform. I tried to set the sort order of the canvas to 10, but that didn't help.

Is there any way I can show a rawImage in the prefab but make it render at the correct position?

Comment: You need to show code and prefab info and so on tbh

Comment: Added code, but I don't think that code makes a difference

Comment: Is your code actually setting the parent? It seems odd unity provide a set parent. Also. You can do it in one go. Which if the parent ia scaled may give different results

Comment: could you show a picture of the result (+ Inspector of your raw image) vs what you would expect it to look like? I suspect it is just something about the `RectTransform` settings (pivot, anchor, etc)

Answer (score 0):

A RawImage is an UI element, so uses a RectTransform rather than a regular Transform.

You may want to set its position by anchoredPosition instead.

`obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = pos;`

If you want to place it in the same place as another RectTransform:

`obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = anotherRectTransform.anchoredPosition;`

Or if you want to place it based on a world position, first you have to convert that position to screen space:

`obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPos);`